# Android - How to relaunch an app in background without restarting it?

Tags: appium, appium-android

I want to open an app and then navigate to settings and comeback to app and continue from the place were i left.

Tried using noReset and fullReset but nthgn worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can relaunch app with using  any page (Splash screen in below example) activity of Application from where you want to open app.

```
public static void launchActivity(Activity activityName) 
{

        ((AndroidDriver<MobileElement>) driver).startActivity(activityName);
}
```

**How you can call this function**

Suppose you have below app package and activity (its for example but you have to use for your app)

```
String appPackage ="my.app.helloworld";

String appActivity = "my.app.helloworld".common.activity.SplashScreen";

launchActivity(new Activity(appPackage, appActivity));
```

Comment: When i use StartActivity the app start new. I want to continue from were i left. To elaborate need to navigate to settings from the App and change the device date and come back to app from the screen were i left.

Comment: You have pass that page activity  in place of appActivity in above function. You can get through “currentActivity” method or pass hardcoded in above function.

Comment: If you are still facing problem let me know

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.launchApp();` to come back the previous apps and activity.

```
driver.launchApp();
```

Answer (score 0):

use driver.activateApp(app_bundleId); to get back to previous state of the app.